Zeitwerk and Namespacing STI Models
I am trying to figure out an issue I am having with my rails app that involves namespacing some sti models.
Originally, I had a collection of sti models located in: app/models/foo
I validated these models against json schemas located in app/models/schemas
I tested these models from specs in spec/models/foo
with factories from spec/factories/foo
My primary model Primary (from which the sti models are linked) did have a method that points to the schemas directory to load everything up.
As is, all is well.
However, I figured I would do something "simple" and move my schemas into a categorized subdirectory to match that of the models, specs, and factories. Seemed like a smart idea.
So, I imagined that I would need to figure out a way to take my sti models, and derive a way to generate the proper path for the schemas so that it looks in the right directory based on its category. For now, I have bar, but in the future I plan on adding baz and qux.
Searching online, it seemed like the first/easiest solution is to namespace the models. That way I can pull that namespace to generate the directory name in my method to point at the json schema path. At least, that is the idea. I don't get far enough to try this out.
So, I namespace one of my models:
module Foo
class Bar < ::Primary
..
end

which matches my file structure (models/foo/bar.rb)
But when I try to check my Zeitwerk or enter a console I get the error: expected file /../app/models/foo/bar.rb to define constant Bar, but didn't.
I was reading online and found solutions that involved creating a foo.rb file in my app/models directory containing a empty module for Foo, but that didn't work either.
(The Zeitwerk documentation seems to imply that this file is not needed)
Specifically, the documentation says (in explicit namespaces):

Classes and modules that act as namespaces can also be explicitly
defined, though. For instance, consider
app/models/hotel.rb         -> Hotel app/models/hotel/pricing.rb ->
Hotel::Pricing
There, app/models/hotel.rb defines Hotel, and thus Zeitwerk does not
autovivify a module.
The classes and modules from the namespace are already available in
the body of the class or module defining it:
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord   include Pricing # works   ... end

So, according to the error, Zeitwerk is expecting bar.rb to define constant Bar, but didn't. If I explicitly create the definition - Bar = Foo::Bar then everything works. However, this seems like something isn't right. I would imagine from the documentation that this shouldn't be needed.
I get that technically, Bar is not being explicitly defined (as it is contained within the module Foo) but the documentation seems to point to that format.Obviously, I am missing something.
So, I guess I am looking for clarification on how I should be namespacing these models to get them to work. Or, should I not even attempt to namespace the models and use a different approach to allow for me to match the file structure of the json schemas to that of my models/specs/factories instead of dumping everything in one directory?
For what it is worth, I am using Rails 7.0.8.4. I did see that Rails 7.1x seems to have improved namespace support for core directories like /lib but I don't know if upgrading to 7.1x would make any difference.

This section of the autoloading guide covers some approaches for STIs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#single-table-inheritance.

can you share your zeitwerk configuration

Thanks for that - I tried following: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#option-3-preload-a-regular-directory which I think matches what I am trying to do. I still have the same issue where zeitwerk is expecting the subclass to define the constant with the same name, but since that is defined within a module, it fails.

Thanks to Xavier Noria! After trying the initializer from the documentation provided, and then updating all of my factories and specs, it appears to have done the trick. Back to all of the tests passing, and my schemas are now in their own namespaced directory, nice and organized! Thanks
